# Save queries in VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro

How to  save queries on disk.I use the TO  clause(example:SELECT * FROM vendors TO w.qpr).Everything works,but when I run the query with DO  i receive the following error:
http://s52.radikal.ru/i138/1201/2f/15765ffe2346.png
And what should I change in order to obtain the query like in query designer,I mean that the query should appear in browse window,but using the command mode.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TO clause is for storing the results of the query, not the query itself. (And, TO is a VFP extension; INTO is preferred.)

If you want to save the query, open up a PRG file (MODIFY COMMAND) and write the query there, then save it.

If you simply omit the TO or INTO clause, the query results will appear in a BROWSE window. Alternatively, use INTO CURSOR and give a cursor name, then issue BROWSE to browse the cursor.

Tamar

Answer (score 0):

As in the other answer, use MODIFY command to make a .prg for your select code.

The INTO clause is for the result.

```
SELECT * FROM zip INTO CURSOR c_zip
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM zip INTO TABLE c:\temp\test
```

If you want a XLS or  CSV or something,  select into a cursor then use

```
EXPORT TO c:\temp\zip.csv XL5
```

To save a query file
Do `File`, `New`,  and select `QUERY` radio button.